# How to get Edit text value from grid view into array android

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I want get edit text value from grid view like the image below. I tried every code but it is not working. Please check this.

[image: here]

Comment: Post what you tried ..

Comment: what code have u tried paste your adapter code here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xnj785sb963uyg/Reciptscannar_grid.java?dl=0 please check this Link Base Adapter demo.

Comment: what is not working saving values?

Comment: In image Upload Adapter, When i wrote titles in edittext then i have to get its  titles and put them into array and send it to server.

Comment: Please give some solution any demo.. That i can do it. Please its a huge request you all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ImageListuplaodAdapter you have
**public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList()** and in

```
public int getCount() {
       /* return bitmaplist.size();*/
        return myItems.size();
    }
```

you are returning its size but myItems is nowhwre initialized.You have a constructor

```
public ImageListuplaodAdapter() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.caption = "Caption" + i;
            myItems.add(listItem);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

but  you are not calling it from anywhere.

 To make it work as per your requirement  do this:
1. keep global List editTextValues = new ArrayList();

2. In your ImageListuplaodAdapter's afterTextChanged(Editable s) save the entered String into list as

```
list.add(editText.getText().toString());
```

3. Then send it to server

Comment: ThanQ , im trying this.

Comment: No Sir it didn't worked. Can you Please do changes in that.

Comment: changes where.In your shared file?

Comment: Yes sir, If you may. I get this response EditText Values: [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , k, k, k, k, k, k, k, k, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , keep, keep, keep, keep, keep, keep, keep, keep, , y, y, y, y, y, y, y, y, , , , , you have any, you have any, you have any, you have any, you have any, you have any, you have any, you have any, , h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h, , , , , , , helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping, helping]

Comment: @PawandeepKaur: have a look at this https://github.com/gosemathraj/GridViewEdittext. I have created a simple module which stores the values entered into edittext in gridview.

Comment: Okay Sir. Thanks a Lot.